# C++ constructors and clarification on how to instantiate

Tags: c++, class, gcc

I asked a question that resulted in some confusion on Class instantiation.

If you have a class A() like:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};
```

Then I want to work with that class, all of the following can be done:

```
// First way
A a1;
// Second way
A a1 = A();
// Third way
A::A a1 = A::A();
// Fourth way
A* a1 = new A();
```

I was told that the 3rd way `A::A a1 = A::A();` isn't appropriate but it does seem to work.

Can anyone explain all these ways and when to use one over the other? I think the `new` allocates on the heap instead of stack?

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
    public: 
    A();
    ~A();
};

A::A()
{
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}

A::~A() {}

int main()
{   
     A a1;

    A a2 = A();

    A::A a3 = A::A();

    A* a4 = new A();

    return 0;
 }
```

output:

```
$ ./test4
A
A
A
A
```

So in g++ 4.2 it does work.

```
$ g++ -Wall main3.cpp -o test4
main3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main3.cpp:28: warning: unused variable ‘a4’
```

In gcc 4.8, not so much:

```
 g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -Wall main3.cpp -o test4
main3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main3.cpp:26:2: error: ‘A::A’ names the constructor, not the type
 A::A a3 = A::A();
 ^
main3.cpp:26:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a3’
  A::A a3 = A::A();
       ^
main3.cpp:26:18: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
  A::A a3 = A::A();
              ^
main3.cpp:28:8: warning: unused variable ‘a4’ [-Wunused-variable]
     A* a4 = new A();
        ^
```

Comment: Asking here is wrong, because we can only take a few minutes to answer your question. Better take several hours to study a good C++ programming book. C++ is a difficult language to learn, you need many hours for that. Also, enable debugging information and warnings with your compiler (e.g. compile with `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux) and learn to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux).

Comment: I don't think the 3rd form works ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3c6b93406db9ef317b83a5f19c79a30d-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc)).

Comment: @Andy, thanks for that. I prompted me to try g++ 4.2 and 4.8, see the update above.

Comment: @Jason so take it out of your example, and please don't ever use it. Visual C++ lets you do it for archaic reasons, by ignoring the 'A::'s in the line.

Comment: a3 is accepted till gcc 4.4, flagged as error from 4.5 -- they fixed the bug. A::A is constructor of class A, not a type, so must be rejected.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Pretty sure you should add `-Werror -pedantic` to that bucket, **especially** while learning.

Comment: @TC1 - I looked up those flags. Good idea!. Thanks for mentioning them.

Comment: I think you'll find that [**10** Constructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html) from the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/index.html) is a great place to start on your quest to understand constructors. Also see [Constructors and destructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) from the [C++ Language Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

Comment: @DavidRR. The whole website in general seems ver useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your object the first two versions are identical (formally, the second includes another copy, but that's optimized away by about any compiler worth its salt). However, there are objects where they are not identical:

If you did *not* write your own default constructor (even if it is empty) and the object does *not* have static storage duration (in your code, it has automatic storage duration), the first version will not initialize any POD members, while the second one will zero-initialize them in any case.

On the other hand, if your class doesn't support copying (you explicitly made the copy constructor private or, in C++11, deleted it and also didn't provide a move constructor), then the second form will be ill-formed (even though the copy doesn't actually take place, logically it is there).

Your third form is not legal C++; if your compiler accepts it it's either a bug or a non-standard extension (I'd bet on a bug, though).

The fourth form does dynamic allocation, that is, it is your responsibility to explicitly destroy it again (using `delete a4;`). Also note that what gets stored in a4 is not the object itself, but a pointer to it; this means that to access the object you have to explicitly dereference the pointer.

Note that since C++11, there's a new form for initialization, which is especially preferable for empty argument lists, because it combines the advantages of the first two versions: It works also on non-copyable/non-movable objects, and it initialized also PODs:

```
A a5{};
```

Comment: Actually, the third form is legal if `A` names a valid namespace.

Comment: @greatwolf: Which it doesn't in the given example program.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it since it might mislead the OP into thinking that that isn't legal C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st initializes `a1` using the default constructor.

The 2nd first initializes `a2` using the default constructor and then assigns to it the object created by the explicite call to the default constructor.

I don't think the 3rd form works so I leave it out.

The last one allocates memory of the appropriate size to store a object of the class A and initializes the allocated memory using the called constructor (default constructor in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You should learn the difference between dynamic and static allocation.  Beyond that, the first form is what you want to use, as it implicitly calls the default constructor.  In the second form, you're creating a temporary instance of a class A and creating a1 using its auto-generated copy constructor, however most compilers will just optimize that down to a single default construction of a1.  The third form is just plain invalid C++.  The forth form is performing dynamic allocation, and you have not properly deallocated your memory with delete, so you've left it up to your OS to reclaim the memory when the program exits.